# IE11 and IFrame history object

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, history, internet-explorer-11

We have an app with a list, that when a record is clicked a popup modal div is displayed, that is used to edit a user record. The div contains an iframe.

In the iframe, the user clicks save and the form is posted back, where server side validation occurs. If there is an error, the user is presented the error information and a go back button.

The go back button is wired to history.go(-1)

When it is clicked, in IE8/9/10 and Chrome, the iframe reverts back to the form with the user's changes still in it, allowing them to remedy any problems.

In IE11, it sends the parent page back to it's last page, so not only do you lose the div, but you lose the list.

Is there a way I can make IE11 behave like it was in IE10?

FWIW, we do perform basic client validation, such as checking for valid emails, mandatory fields etc, but we also do this in the backend, as well as checking that more complex rules to do with business relationships etc.

Thanks!

Comment: We had users report this behavior and I have verified it as well, but with Framesets and Frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With IE11 finally going HTML5, you can save your history state so you would use push and popstate. Using this, you'll be able to control your "back" (working fine here).

Comment: Thanks Miraino I ended up using some pushstate and popstate to sort this issue in IE11.